# Why are some KeyEvent keycodes throwing "IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key code"?

Tags: java

I'm trying to automate some processes using `Robot` and it seems certain keycodes (only symbols that require you to hold shift when typing it normally) in `KeyEvent` are throwing an `IllegalArgumentException`. This is all the code that's running in `main`:

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_EXCLAMATION_MARK);
```

However, it works fine using the following workaround:

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
```

Any ideas why the exception is thrown? Thanks!

Java version: 1.6.0_23

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because like the documentation for `Robot.keyPress` says, an `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown when the `keycode` doesn't represent a valid key, and `VK_EXCLAMATION_MARK` is not a valid key.

Keycodes are used to represent two things: keys on the keyboard, and "a character was typed" events. Typing a character often requires more than one keypress (in sequence, or simultaneously, or both). But `Robot.keyPress` simulates the act of pressing a key (hence the name), not the act of typing a character.

For more information, see the documentation for KeyEvent: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know `Robot`, but isn't that because it needs to be two keys pressed to an exclamation mark to be inserted.

There are no exclamation mark key on the keyboards.