# java.awt.Robot.keyPress throws IllegalArgumentException when when pressing quotation mark key

Tags: java, keyevent, awtrobot

When you try to use Robot.keyPress to type a `"` (double quotation mark) it throws a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key code.

How can I fix or get around this?

If it helps, I am currently on Windows.

Test code:

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        try {
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_QUOTEDBL);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key code
    at sun.awt.windows.WRobotPeer.keyPress(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Robot.keyPress(Robot.java:358)
```

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 12.04 x64. However, it only prints a single quote instead of a double.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are some KeyEvent keycodes throwing "IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key code"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634375/why-are-some-keyevent-keycodes-throwing-illegalargumentexception-invalid-key-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're getting an error because there isn't a `"` key on your keyboard.  `"` will almost certainly be on one of the keys of your keyboard but it will quite probably be shifted.  Instead of trying to 'press' `"`, you should be 'pressing' Shift and the 'base' character for that key, i.e. the one you get if you type that key on its own.

I found that running the following class in a command-prompt left me with a `"` character:

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        try {
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_2);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

On a UK keyboard (which I'm using), the `"` character is shifted `2`, which is why I'm using `KeyEvent.VK_2`.  It may be in other places on other keyboards - if I remember correctly, it's shifted single-quote on a US keyboard.  In that case, you would use `VK_QUOTE` instead of `VK_2`.

I also found that releasing the `VK_SHIFT` keypress was necessary to avoid all sorts of weirdness with Windows thinking the Shift key was still held down.

Comment: Aha, that's also why it was only putting a single quote on my machine. You should always remember to release a key after pressing it with a `Robot`, if you don't (at least on my machine) it'll continue to send that key event, resulting in hundreds of quotes appearing.

Comment: Is there any non-layout-dependent way? (Without using clipboard)