# Displaying keypress count in JTextField or Jbutton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield, keyevent

I'm having trouble displaying the amount of times a key has been pressed and display the number in a JTextField or JButton. Could anyone give me a hand with that?

I already have the KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD3 displayed, it just seems to be the KeyEvent.VK_2 that I am having such trouble with:

I can display it but the number doesn't update each time the key is pressed.

Here is my full code.. bit big but you asked for it.. :)

```
    public class Display extends JFrame{

public static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = 1000;
public static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 450;
public static final Color LINE_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
public static final Color GROUND_COLOR = Color.GREEN;
public static final Color CANVAS_BACKGROUND = Color.CYAN;
public static final int TRANS = Color.OPAQUE;

private int x1 = CANVAS_WIDTH / 2;
private int y1 = CANVAS_HEIGHT / 2;
private int x2 = CANVAS_WIDTH /2;
private int y2 = CANVAS_HEIGHT / 2;

private int Sx1 = CANVAS_WIDTH ;
private int Sy1 = CANVAS_HEIGHT ;
private int Sy2 = CANVAS_HEIGHT ; 

private int Rx1 = CANVAS_WIDTH - CANVAS_WIDTH;
private int Ry1 = CANVAS_HEIGHT;
private int Rx2 = CANVAS_WIDTH;
private int Ry2 = CANVAS_HEIGHT ;

private int Lx1 = CANVAS_WIDTH / 2;
private int Ly1 = CANVAS_HEIGHT / 2;
private int Lx2 = CANVAS_WIDTH / 2;
private int Ly2 = CANVAS_HEIGHT / 2;

private int Mx1 = CANVAS_WIDTH / 2;
private int My1 = CANVAS_HEIGHT / 2;
private int Mx2 = CANVAS_WIDTH / 2;
private int My2 = CANVAS_HEIGHT / 2;

int[] xs = {380, 460, 460, 540, 540, 620, 500, 380};
    int[] ys = {260, 260, 250, 250, 260, 260, 205, 260};

private DrawCanvas canvas;
private JTextField Altitude;
private JTextField TASpeed;
private JLabel altButton;
private int countA = 0;
private int countS = 0;
private int Bcount1 = 0;
public String Ccount = Integer.toString(Bcount1);



public class CountUpAltitude extends AbstractAction {
      /** Constructor */
      public CountUpAltitude(String name, String shortDesc, Integer mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, shortDesc);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_3);
         Bcount1 += 1;
      }
      //RIGHT
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
                    switch(evt.getKeyCode()) {
                    case KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD6:
            //original count
            countA += 5;
            Altitude.setText(countA + "");
                    }
                }
              });
      }
   }

   public class CountDownAltitude extends AbstractAction {
      /** Constructor */
      public CountDownAltitude(String name, String shortDesc, Integer mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, shortDesc);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_4);
      }
      //RIGHT
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
                switch(evt.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD3:
          //original count
          countA -= 5;
          Altitude.setText(countA + "");
                }
            }
          });
      }
   }

   public class CountUpTASpeed extends AbstractAction {
          /** Constructor */
          public CountUpTASpeed(String name, String shortDesc, Integer     mnemonic) {
             super(name);
             putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, shortDesc);
             putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_1);

          }
          //LEFT
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
                        switch(evt.getKeyCode()) {
                        case KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD4:
                //original count
                countS += 5;
                TASpeed.setText(countS + "");
                        }
                    }
                  });
          }
       }

   public class CountDownTASpeed extends AbstractAction {
          /** Constructor */
          public CountDownTASpeed(String name, String shortDesc, Integer     mnemonic) {
             super(name);
             putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, shortDesc);
             putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_2);
          }
          //LEFT
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
                    switch(evt.getKeyCode()) {
                    case KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD1:
              //original count
              countS -= 5;
              TASpeed.setText(countS + "");
                    }
                }
              });
          }
       }



public Display() {
    canvas = new DrawCanvas();
    canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT));
    canvas.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    Container cp = getContentPane();
    cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


     // Create the Actions shared by the button and keys
    Action countUpAltitude = new CountUpAltitude("Count Up",
            "", new Integer(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER));
    Action countDownAltitude = new CountDownAltitude("Count Down",
            "", new Integer(KeyEvent.VK_D));

    Action countUpTASpeed = new CountUpTASpeed("Count Up",
            "", new Integer(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER));
    Action countDownTASpeed = new CountDownTASpeed("Count Down",
            "", new Integer(KeyEvent.VK_D));






      Altitude = new JTextField("0", 5);
      Altitude.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
      Altitude.setEditable(false);
      Altitude.setOpaque(false);
      Altitude.setFont(Altitude.getFont().deriveFont(25f));

      TASpeed = new JTextField("0", 5);
      TASpeed.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
      TASpeed.setEditable(false);
      TASpeed.setOpaque(false);
      TASpeed.setFont(Altitude.getFont().deriveFont(25f));

      altButton = new JLabel();
      altButton.setText(Ccount);

      canvas.add(altButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


      canvas.add(Altitude, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
      canvas.add(TASpeed, BorderLayout.LINE_START);


      //Invisible
      JButton btnCountUp = new JButton();
      btnCountUp.setFocusable(false);
      btnCountUp.setHideActionText(true);
//        btnCountUp.setContentAreaFilled(false);
//        btnCountUp.setBorderPainted(false);
      canvas.add(btnCountUp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      //Invisible
      JButton btnCountDown = new JButton();
      btnCountDown.setFocusable(false);
      btnCountDown.setHideActionText(true);
    //        btnCountDown.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    //        btnCountDown.setBorderPainted(false);
      canvas.add(btnCountDown, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      // Set actions for buttons
      btnCountUp.setAction(countUpAltitude);
      btnCountDown.setAction(countDownAltitude);


      JButton btnCountUpS = new JButton();
      btnCountUpS.setFocusable(false);
      btnCountUpS.setHideActionText(true);
//        btnCountUpS.setContentAreaFilled(false);
//        btnCountUpS.setBorderPainted(false);
      canvas.add(btnCountUpS, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      //Invisible
      JButton btnCountDownS = new JButton();
      btnCountDownS.setFocusable(false);
      btnCountDownS.setHideActionText(true);
//        btnCountDownS.setContentAreaFilled(false);
//        btnCountDownS.setBorderPainted(false);
      canvas.add(btnCountDownS, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      // Set actions for buttons
      btnCountUpS.setAction(countUpTASpeed);
      btnCountDownS.setAction(countDownTASpeed);


    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
            switch(evt.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                Rx1 -= 10;      Ry1 += 10;
                Rx2 += 10;      Ry2 -= 10;
                x1 -=10;        x2 +=10;
                Mx1 += 10;      Mx2 -= 10;
                repaint();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                Rx1 -= 10;      Ry1 -= 10;
                Rx2 += 10;      Ry2 += 10;
                x1 += 10;       x2 += 10;
                Mx1 -= 10;      Mx2 += 10;
                repaint();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                y1 -= 10;       y2 -= 10;
                Ly1 -= 10;      Ly2 -= 10;
                Sy1 += 10;      Sy2 -= 10;
                Ry1 +=10;       Ry2 += 10;
                repaint();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                y1 += 10;       y2 += 10;
                Ly1 += 10;      Ly2 += 10;
                Sy1 -= 10;      Sy2 += 10;
                Ry1 -= 10;      Ry2 -= 10;
                repaint();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_M:
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    });
    cp.add(canvas, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("FLIGHT DISPLAY");
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
    requestFocus();
}

class DrawCanvas extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        setBackground(CANVAS_BACKGROUND);

        g.setColor(GROUND_COLOR);
        //Draw ground Color
        g.drawRect(Sx1 - Sx1,Sy1 /2, CANVAS_WIDTH, Sy2 /2);
        g.fillRect(Sx1 - Sx1, Sy1 /2, CANVAS_WIDTH, Sy2 /2);
        g.setColor(LINE_COLOR);
        //Draw line centre horizontal
        g.drawLine(Rx1, Ry1 /2, Rx2, Ry2 /2);
        g.drawOval(x1 -15, y1 -15, 30, 30);
        g.fillOval(x1 - 5, y1 -5, 10, 10);
        //Draw line centre vertical

        //Draw line dim
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillArc(300, 0, 400, 140, 0, 180);
        g.setColor(LINE_COLOR);
        g.drawLine(Lx1 -25, Ly1 +20, Lx2 +25, Ly2 +20);
        g.drawLine(Lx1 -50, Ly1 +40, Lx2 +50, Ly2 +40);
        g.drawLine(Lx1 -25, Ly1 +60, Lx2 +25, Ly2 +60);
        g.drawLine(Lx1 -75, Ly1 +80, Lx2 +75, Ly2 +80);
        g.drawLine(Lx1 -25, Ly1 +100, Lx2 +25, Ly2 +100);
        //Draw line dim
        g.drawLine(Lx1 -25, Ly1 -20, Lx2 +25, Ly2 -20);
        g.drawLine(Lx1 -50, Ly1 -40, Lx2 +50, Ly2 -40);
        g.drawLine(Lx1 -25, Ly1 -60, Lx2 +25, Ly2 -60);
        g.drawLine(Lx1 -75, Ly1 -80, Lx2 +75, Ly2 -80);
        g.drawLine(Lx1 -25, Ly1 -100, Lx2 +25, Ly2 -100);
        //Draw polyline centre plane
        g.drawPolyline(xs, ys, 8);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawArc(300, 0, 400, 140,  0, 180);
        g.drawLine(Mx1+30, My1 + My1, Mx2, My2 - My2);
        g.drawLine(Mx1-30, My1 + My1, Mx2, My2 - My2);
        g.drawLine(Mx1, My1 + My1, Mx2, My2 - My2);

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Display();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Check [this][1], Can you tell which key are you having issues with?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923033/java-awt-robot-keypress-throws-illegalargumentexception-when-when-pressing-quota

Comment: nopes this doesnt really help as im not using a robot and im trying to display the amount of presses on a button or textfield not a printStackTrace. and the key im having trouble with is the putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_2); line of my above code.. im tring to display how many times this key is pressed!!

Comment: Why are you adding a KeyListener into an AbstractAction? This confuses me to no end. What is your goal if alt-2 is pressed? The bottom button gets depressed, but no action will occur since all the code in the actionPerformed is contained in a strange KeyListener. On a side note, why use KeyListeners at all and not Key Bindings? They're a much better fit for Swing applications.

Comment: Also, don't forget to cast your Graphics object to a Graphics2D object as this will allow you to set your RenderingHints to allow proper antialiasing of your drawings.

Comment: Also, what is the purposes of the very skinny buttons? Why are they in the GUI at all? Note that if you use Key Bindings, you don't have to worry about other components grabbing the focus since the bindings should work (if done right) regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KeyEvent.VK_2 is nothing but the Key with Number 2 in the non-numpad area on a standard US Keyboard.

```
public static final int VK_2              = 0x32;
```

The below code works fine for me, I would not expect that you have not added a switch case for this key, so can you do a small testing to print the ASCII value of the desired key and find out what it actually corresponds to in the KeyEvent class.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_2:
            System.out.println("Non Numpad 2");
        case KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD3:
            System.out.println("NumPad 3");
    }
}
```

Comment: well i actually do have a switch for a variety of buttons and all work fine except the non numpad 2 i want to display how many times it gets pressed not that it was pressed.. at the moment mu numpad 3 counts down numbers and the non-numpad 2 has to b pressed to initialize the numpad3.. and i want to display how many times the non-numpad 2 has been pressed therefore showing how many times the numpad 3 has been initialized..

Comment: BenJi, declaring a class variable to increment the number of times the key was pressed whenever the VK_2 key is pressed does help. I do not understand about the initialization part. Did you mean you want to dynamically initialize the Numpad3 the number of times the VK_2 key is pressed. Would you posting the program that you tried to achieve this? My email id is in my profile

Comment: i posted the full code above.. hope this helps you to help me :)

Comment: I cant find an issue with your code tbh, pressing ALT+2(non-numpad) does end up enabling your NUMPAD1 key. Just added a bit more of console output for the key presses and pasted http://pastebin.com/bzieBe4E

Comment: Thanks man exatly what i needed!! all i have to do now is assign it to a button on my gui thak again!!