# Java Robot - Check Symbol Key

Tags: java, keyboard, awt, keypress, awtrobot

My current project involves automation using Java's Robot class, to simulate key presses.
My problem is that certain keycodes are invalid to pass to the Robot's `keypress(int keycode)` method.

#### What I already know:

After reading the solution to this question: [Why are some KeyEvent keycodes throwing IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key ocode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634375/why-are-some-keyevent-keycodes-throwing-illegalargumentexception-invalid-key-c), I started modifying my code, changing certain symbols like `£ (VK_DOLLAR)` to `VK_SHIFT + VK_3`, `& (VK_AMPERSAND)` to `VK_SHIT + VK_7`, etc ...

#### My question:

My question, however is how to determine what key gives what symbol when combined with shift, since different keyboards (and often times different keyboard configurations from the OS) change these.

A typical example is the `@ (at symbol) and " (double quote)`. `VK_SHIFT + VK_2` may be the at symbol on some systems while maybe a double quote on others.

Is there anyway in Java to check, prior to invoking the Robot keypress, on which key a symbol relies ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you assume the keyboard layout won't change over time?

Comment: That statement is a little ironic coming from someone named Dvorak! :)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels don't worry, a Dvorak keyboard shares the shift mapping with QWERTY, just the keys are at different positions.

Comment: Why not just assume the shift-mapping is compatible with the UK keyboard?

Comment: If all else fails, you can always ask the user how to get a particular symbol.

Comment: i'm a little confused - if you were to remove your keyboard from the computer entirely, the Robot class would still function as, presumably, the default QWERTY layout. since changing the hardware, presumably, does nothing: under what circumstances would your code actually fail, and what causes that fail? if i plugged in a keyboard to my computer with odd shift mappings, does the robot class actually simulate the keyboard layout? how does the robot class know the shift mappings? if the OS is controlling the behavior, i don't think there is any straightforward solution to your problem.

Comment: @AlexLynch No the Robot class uses the 'software keyboard', meaning the OS configuration.

Comment: @JanDvorak I guess I could set up some type of configuration. I just would have preferred having the entire program automated, with settings and all. But at this point I seems like the only reasonable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already went through IllegalArgumentException when using robots. It's because of your keyboard layout. My solution was to use Alt codes:

```
public static void alt(int event1, int event2, int event3, int event4) throws Exception {

Robot bot = new Robot();
bot.delay(50); //Optional
    bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);

        bot.keyPress(event1);
        bot.keyRelease(event1);

        bot.keyPress(event2);
        bot.keyRelease(event2);

        bot.keyPress(event3);
        bot.keyRelease(event3);

        bot.keyPress(event4);
        bot.keyRelease(event4);

    bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);

}
```

It makes easy to send Alt codes.

For example, if you want an ampersand just use `alt(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0, KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0, KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD3, KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD8);`

You just got to make sure Num Lock is on.

A useful site to get the alt codes you'll need is http://www.alt-codes.net/

Comment: +1 for helpful answer and working example. This is bound to work, since alt codes aren't subject to change. Just what I need. Thanks :)

Comment: Some JAVA apps does not support Alt Codes...
It seems, we really need a big database of keyboard mappings, or get it from system.

Comment: While it would work in Windows environment, It doesn't work in Linux. In Linux pressing ALT + NUMBER doesn't output the character.