# Invalid key code @ java

Tags: java, keyboard, awtrobot

I'm working on a system to type things automatically with java. This is how I write it:

```
public void typeMessage(String message) {
    for (char c : message.toCharArray()) {
        int code = c;
        if (code > 96 && code < 123) 
            code = code - 32;
        if (c == '@') {
            robot.keyPress(VK_SHIFT);
            robot.keyPress(VK_AT);
            robot.keyRelease(VK_SHIFT);
            robot.keyRelease(VK_AT);
        } else {
            type(code);
        }
    }
    type(VK_ENTER);
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
    Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key code
```

on

```
    robot.keyPress(VK_AT);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634375/why-are-some-keyevent-keycodes-throwing-illegalargumentexception-invalid-key-c

Comment: I think you can refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923033/java-awt-robot-keypress-throws-illegalargumentexception-when-when-pressing-quota

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your keyboard layout should have a key for the @ symbol for this code to work. Does it?

If your keyboard is set up with an American layout you need to type shift+2 to type an @ symbol, and instead of VK_AT you have to use VK_2.

Answer (score 7):

The Class didnt reach all ascii characters, but can resolve your problem, costumize it.

KeyboardKeys kk = new KeyboardKeys();

kk.keyPress('@');

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent.*;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.*;

public class KeyboardKeys {

private Robot robot;

public KeyboardKeys() throws AWTException {
    this.robot = new Robot();
}

public KeyboardKeys(Robot robot) {
    this.robot = robot;
}

public void keyPress(char characterKey){

    switch (characterKey){
        case '☺': altNumpad("1"); break;
        case '☻': altNumpad("2"); break;
        case '♥': altNumpad("3"); break;
        case '♦': altNumpad("4"); break;
        case '♣': altNumpad("5"); break;
        case '♠': altNumpad("6"); break;
        case '♂': altNumpad("11"); break;
        case '♀': altNumpad("12"); break;
        case '♫': altNumpad("14"); break;
        case '☼': altNumpad("15"); break;
        case '►': altNumpad("16"); break;
        case '◄': altNumpad("17"); break;
        case '↕': altNumpad("18"); break;
        case '‼': altNumpad("19"); break;
        case '¶': altNumpad("20"); break;
        case '§': altNumpad("21"); break;
        case '▬': altNumpad("22"); break;
        case '↨': altNumpad("23"); break;
        case '↑': altNumpad("24"); break;
        case '↓': altNumpad("25"); break;
        case '→': altNumpad("26"); break;
        case '←': altNumpad("27"); break;
        case '∟': altNumpad("28"); break;
        case '↔': altNumpad("29"); break;
        case '▲': altNumpad("30"); break;
        case '▼': altNumpad("31"); break;
        case '!': altNumpad("33"); break;
        case '"': altNumpad("34"); break;
        case '#': altNumpad("35"); break;
        case '$': altNumpad("36"); break;
        case '%': altNumpad("37"); break;
        case '&': altNumpad("38"); break;
        case '\'': altNumpad("39"); break;
        case '(': altNumpad("40"); break;
        case ')': altNumpad("41"); break;
        case '*': altNumpad("42"); break;
        case '+': altNumpad("43"); break;
        case ',': altNumpad("44"); break;
        case '-': altNumpad("45"); break;
        case '.': altNumpad("46"); break;
        case '/': altNumpad("47"); break;
        case '0': altNumpad("48"); break;
        case '1': altNumpad("49"); break;
        case '2': altNumpad("50"); break;
        case '3': altNumpad("51"); break;
        case '4': altNumpad("52"); break;
        case '5': altNumpad("53"); break;
        case '6': altNumpad("54"); break;
        case '7': altNumpad("55"); break;
        case '8': altNumpad("56"); break;
        case '9': altNumpad("57"); break;
        case ':': altNumpad("58"); break;
        case ';': altNumpad("59"); break;
        case '<': altNumpad("60"); break;
        case '=': altNumpad("61"); break;
        case '>': altNumpad("62"); break;
        case '?': altNumpad("63"); break;
        case '@': altNumpad("64"); break;
        case 'A': altNumpad("65"); break;
        case 'B': altNumpad("66"); break;
        case 'C': altNumpad("67"); break;
        case 'D': altNumpad("68"); break;
        case 'E': altNumpad("69"); break;
        case 'F': altNumpad("70"); break;
        case 'G': altNumpad("71"); break;
        case 'H': altNumpad("72"); break;
        case 'I': altNumpad("73"); break;
        case 'J': altNumpad("74"); break;
        case 'K': altNumpad("75"); break;
        case 'L': altNumpad("76"); break;
        case 'M': altNumpad("77"); break;
        case 'N': altNumpad("78"); break;
        case 'O': altNumpad("79"); break;
        case 'P': altNumpad("80"); break;
        case 'Q': altNumpad("81"); break;
        case 'R': altNumpad("82"); break;
        case 'S': altNumpad("83"); break;
        case 'T': altNumpad("84"); break;
        case 'U': altNumpad("85"); break;
        case 'V': altNumpad("86"); break;
        case 'W': altNumpad("87"); break;
        case 'X': altNumpad("88"); break;
        case 'Y': altNumpad("89"); break;
        case 'Z': altNumpad("90"); break;
        case '[': altNumpad("91"); break;
        case '\\': altNumpad("92"); break;
        case ']': altNumpad("93"); break;
        case '^': altNumpad("94"); break;
        case '_': altNumpad("95"); break;
        case '`': altNumpad("96"); break;
        case 'a': altNumpad("97"); break;
        case 'b': altNumpad("98"); break;
        case 'c': altNumpad("99"); break;
        case 'd': altNumpad("100"); break;
        case 'e': altNumpad("101"); break;
        case 'f': altNumpad("102"); break;
        case 'g': altNumpad("103"); break;
        case 'h': altNumpad("104"); break;
        case 'i': altNumpad("105"); break;
        case 'j': altNumpad("106"); break;
        case 'k': altNumpad("107"); break;
        case 'l': altNumpad("108"); break;
        case 'm': altNumpad("109"); break;
        case 'n': altNumpad("110"); break;
        case 'o': altNumpad("111"); break;
        case 'p': altNumpad("112"); break;
        case 'q': altNumpad("113"); break;
        case 'r': altNumpad("114"); break;
        case 's': altNumpad("115"); break;
        case 't': altNumpad("116"); break;
        case 'u': altNumpad("117"); break;
        case 'v': altNumpad("118"); break;
        case 'w': altNumpad("119"); break;
        case 'x': altNumpad("120"); break;
        case 'y': altNumpad("121"); break;
        case 'z': altNumpad("122"); break;
        case '{': altNumpad("123"); break;
        case '|': altNumpad("124"); break;
        case '}': altNumpad("125"); break;
        case '~': altNumpad("126"); break;
        case '⌂': altNumpad("127"); break;
        case 'Ç': altNumpad("128"); break;
        case 'ü': altNumpad("129"); break;
        case 'é': altNumpad("130"); break;
        case 'â': altNumpad("131"); break;
        case 'ä': altNumpad("132"); break;
        case 'à': altNumpad("133"); break;
        case 'å': altNumpad("134"); break;
        case 'ç': altNumpad("135"); break;
        case 'ê': altNumpad("136"); break;
        case 'ë': altNumpad("137"); break;
        case 'è': altNumpad("138"); break;
        case 'ï': altNumpad("139"); break;
        case 'î': altNumpad("140"); break;
        case 'ì': altNumpad("141"); break;
        case 'Ä': altNumpad("142"); break;
        case 'Å': altNumpad("143"); break;
        case 'É': altNumpad("144"); break;
        case 'æ': altNumpad("145"); break;
        case 'Æ': altNumpad("146"); break;
        case 'ô': altNumpad("147"); break;
        case 'ö': altNumpad("148"); break;
        case 'ò': altNumpad("149"); break;
        case 'û': altNumpad("150"); break;
        case 'ù': altNumpad("151"); break;
        case 'ÿ': altNumpad("152"); break;
        case 'Ö': altNumpad("153"); break;
        case 'Ü': altNumpad("154"); break;
        case '¢': altNumpad("155"); break;
        case '£': altNumpad("156"); break;
        case '¥': altNumpad("157"); break;
        case '₧': altNumpad("158"); break;
        case 'ƒ': altNumpad("159"); break;
        case 'á': altNumpad("160"); break;
        case 'í': altNumpad("161"); break;
        case 'ó': altNumpad("162"); break;
        case 'ú': altNumpad("163"); break;
        case 'ñ': altNumpad("164"); break;
        case 'Ñ': altNumpad("165"); break;
        case 'ª': altNumpad("166"); break;
        case 'º': altNumpad("167"); break;
        case '¿': altNumpad("168"); break;
        case '⌐': altNumpad("169"); break;
        case '¬': altNumpad("170"); break;
        case '½': altNumpad("171"); break;
        case '¼': altNumpad("172"); break;
        case '¡': altNumpad("173"); break;
        case '«': altNumpad("174"); break;
        case '»': altNumpad("175"); break;
        case '░': altNumpad("176"); break;
        case '▒': altNumpad("177"); break;
        case '▓': altNumpad("178"); break;
        case '│': altNumpad("179"); break;
        case '┤': altNumpad("180"); break;
        case '╡': altNumpad("181"); break;
        case '╢': altNumpad("182"); break;
        case '╖': altNumpad("183"); break;
        case '╕': altNumpad("184"); break;
        case '╣': altNumpad("185"); break;
        case '║': altNumpad("186"); break;
        case '╗': altNumpad("187"); break;
        case '╝': altNumpad("188"); break;
        case '╜': altNumpad("189"); break;
        case '╛': altNumpad("190"); break;
        case '┐': altNumpad("191"); break;
        case '└': altNumpad("192"); break;
        case '┴': altNumpad("193"); break;
        case '┬': altNumpad("194"); break;
        case '├': altNumpad("195"); break;
        case '─': altNumpad("196"); break;
        case '┼': altNumpad("197"); break;
        case '╞': altNumpad("198"); break;
        case '╟': altNumpad("199"); break;
        case '╚': altNumpad("200"); break;
        case '╔': altNumpad("201"); break;
        case '╩': altNumpad("202"); break;
        case '╦': altNumpad("203"); break;
        case '╠': altNumpad("204"); break;
        case '═': altNumpad("205"); break;
        case '╬': altNumpad("206"); break;
        case '╧': altNumpad("207"); break;
        case '╨': altNumpad("208"); break;
        case '╤': altNumpad("209"); break;
        case '╥': altNumpad("210"); break;
        case '╙': altNumpad("211"); break;
        case '╘': altNumpad("212"); break;
        case '╒': altNumpad("213"); break;
        case '╓': altNumpad("214"); break;
        case '╫': altNumpad("215"); break;
        case '╪': altNumpad("216"); break;
        case '┘': altNumpad("217"); break;
        case '┌': altNumpad("218"); break;
        case '█': altNumpad("219"); break;
        case '▄': altNumpad("220"); break;
        case '▌': altNumpad("221"); break;
        case '▐': altNumpad("222"); break;
        case '▀': altNumpad("223"); break;
        case 'α': altNumpad("224"); break;
        case 'ß': altNumpad("225"); break;
        case 'Γ': altNumpad("226"); break;
        case 'π': altNumpad("227"); break;
        case 'Σ': altNumpad("228"); break;
        case 'σ': altNumpad("229"); break;
        case 'µ': altNumpad("230"); break;
        case 'τ': altNumpad("231"); break;
        case 'Φ': altNumpad("232"); break;
        case 'Θ': altNumpad("233"); break;
        case 'Ω': altNumpad("234"); break;
        case 'δ': altNumpad("235"); break;
        case '∞': altNumpad("236"); break;
        case 'φ': altNumpad("237"); break;
        case 'ε': altNumpad("238"); break;
        case '∩': altNumpad("239"); break;
        case '≡': altNumpad("240"); break;
        case '±': altNumpad("241"); break;
        case '≥': altNumpad("242"); break;
        case '≤': altNumpad("243"); break;
        case '⌠': altNumpad("244"); break;
        case '⌡': altNumpad("245"); break;
        case '÷': altNumpad("246"); break;
        case '≈': altNumpad("247"); break;
        case '°': altNumpad("248"); break;
        case '∙': altNumpad("249"); break;
        case '·': altNumpad("250"); break;
        case '√': altNumpad("251"); break;
        case 'ⁿ': altNumpad("252"); break;
        case '²': altNumpad("253"); break;
        case '■': altNumpad("254"); break;

        default: return;
    }

}

private void altNumpad(int... numpadCodes){
    if (numpadCodes.length == 0) {
        return;
    }

    robot.keyPress(VK_ALT);

    for (int NUMPAD_KEY : numpadCodes){
        robot.keyPress(NUMPAD_KEY);
        robot.keyRelease(NUMPAD_KEY);
    }

    robot.keyRelease(VK_ALT);
}

private void altNumpad(String numpadCodes){
    if (numpadCodes == null || !numpadCodes.matches("^\\d+$")){
        return;
    }               

    robot.keyPress(VK_ALT);

    for (char charater : numpadCodes.toCharArray()){

        int NUMPAD_KEY = getNumpad(charater);

        if (NUMPAD_KEY != -1){
            robot.keyPress(NUMPAD_KEY);
            robot.keyRelease(NUMPAD_KEY);
        }
    }

    robot.keyRelease(VK_ALT);        
}

private int getNumpad(char numberChar){
    switch (numberChar){
        case '0' : return VK_NUMPAD0;
        case '1' : return VK_NUMPAD1;
        case '2' : return VK_NUMPAD2;
        case '3' : return VK_NUMPAD3;
        case '4' : return VK_NUMPAD4;
        case '5' : return VK_NUMPAD5;
        case '6' : return VK_NUMPAD6;
        case '7' : return VK_NUMPAD7;
        case '8' : return VK_NUMPAD8;
        case '9' : return VK_NUMPAD9;
        default: return -1;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

not sure whether this only creating the problem, but you should consider releasing other key before releasing shift.

```
robot.keyRelease(VK_AT);
robot.keyRelease(VK_SHIFT);
```

Comment: It never gets there. It fails at the line before it.